# where is "top level of template tree" in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

in Django I want to add a custom 404 page for my site. as [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) says I must add a 404.html to **top level of my template tree**.
I want to know where it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `templates` directory.  Not `templates/products`, etc.